# Hide referrer on iframe Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, referrer, referrer-policy

I have a iframe where videos played when the user choose. Everything is on my website, but I want to hide the referrer to the user, so they don't know in what page the videos are. I'm trying with referrerpolicy="no-referrer", but in firefox doesn't work, in chrome works fine. Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive video" id="myvideo" src="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: `so they don't know in what page the videos are` - how can hiding the referrer help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is valid, but there are several open [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610450) in firefox that prevent this from working as it should.

You may be able to fix this at the server level though, through the use of the [referrer-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header. Tweak your server config so that the videos are returned with this header set:

```
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

Comment: I am using nginx, I put add_header Referrer-Policy 'no-referrer';  but doesn't work

Comment: If you open More Tools -> Web Developer Tools in firefox, then select the Network tab, and refresh, are the headers present on the video?

Comment: yes, I can see with a extension

Comment: I think the short answer is going to be "firefox is broken for the time being".